# How to merge duplicate cells in Google Sheets with a comma?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am experiencing issues trying to make duplicate cells merging together with a separator instead of summing. I have tried to adapt a script from another question on this forum, where the values from column B were summed based on duplicates in column A. In my case, I have 3 digit numbers in column B, which I would like to be listed in "123, 456, 789" based on a common column A string. Instead, the code returns the values as "123456789".

The code is attached below:

```
function merge() {
var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = target.getSheetByName("CSS");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-1, 2);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var workorders = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  {
    var row = data[i];
    var curCar = row[0];
    var curNumber = row[1];

    // empty name
    if (!curCar.trim())
    {
      continue;
    }

    // if name found first time, save it to object
    if (!workorders[curCar])
    {
      workorders[curCar] = String(curNumber);
    }
    // if duplicate, list strings
    else
    {
      workorders[curCar] += curNumber     
    }
  }
```

I understand that += command should be replaced with + " ," +, but for some reason that does not work correctly.

Does anyone know why does this happen?

Comment: Did you try: workorders[curCar] =  workorders[curCar] + " ," + curNumber

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code working to add the commas in the proper formatting:

```
function merge() {
    var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = target.getSheetByName("CSS");
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, 2);
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    var workorders = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var row = data[i];
        var curCar = row[0];
        var curNumber = row[1];

        // empty name
        if (!curCar.trim()) {
            continue;
        }

        // if name found first time, save it to object
        if (!workorders[curCar]) {
            workorders[curCar] = String(curNumber);
        }
        // if duplicate, list strings
        else {
            workorders[curCar] = workorders[curCar] + ', ' + curNumber; // Changed Line
        }
    }
}
```